# SELECT vs SET, SET not working but SELECT is, why?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have come across a problem whilst using SET and SELECT in SQL Server 2012.

Using the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT @CellNo= Complainants.CellNo FROM Complainants
         INNER JOIN Complaints
         ON Complainants.ComplainantID = Complaints.Complainant_ID
         WHERE Complaints.ComplaintID = @ComplaintID
```

it works; but when I use the following statement:

```
SET @CellNo= Complainants.CellNo from Complainants
         INNER JOIN Complaints
         ON Complainants.ComplainantID = Complaints.Complainant_ID
         WHERE Complaints.ComplaintID = @ComplaintID
```

then it doesn't work; the error that is reported is:

```
Error: Incorrect syntax near FROM
```

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following format for SET Command:

```
SET @CellNo= (Select Complainants.CellNo from Complainants
         inner join Complaints
         ON Complainants.ComplainantID = Complaints.Complainant_ID
         Where Complaints.ComplaintID = @ComplaintID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SET @CellNo = (SELECT Complainants.CellNo
               FROM   Complainants INNER JOIN
                      Complaints ON Complainants.ComplainantID = Complaints.Complainant_ID
               WHERE  Complaints.ComplaintID = @ComplaintID)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem this is a how its supposed to work. You use SET to set variable value and you use SELECT to select data from table. If you need to read data from a column you must use SELECT. Using set with a combinatioin of subselect as suggested will work, but adds extra code.